# How do I make my deployed web app find my static files?

Tags: reactjs, azure, web-deployment

I have an simple react app with some links and a landing page with a video background.
I have run an npm build to create the build folder for my web app which I have deployed on Azure. Everything works except my video background doesnt show up. My other images and icons do.

Im getting an error where the resources manifest.json and my static folder cant be found. I have checked in Azure to see if those files exists, and they do.

[image: Errors im getting in browser]

Here is my web.config. `

```
 https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
```

-->

```
    <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
    <rule name="StaticContent">
      <action type="Rewrite" url="public{PATH_INFO}"/>
    </rule>

    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
    <rule name="DynamicContent">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>

<!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <remove segment="bin"/>
    </hiddenSegments>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>

<!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

<!--
  You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
    * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
    * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
    * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

  See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
-->
<!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
        <remove fileExtension=".json" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```

`

Im sorry if my explenation is bad, im new to azure

Comment: There are two images, one are the errors and one is my web.config which i have in my root folder

Comment: Done! Sorry for the troubble